# Kdenliveのビルドについて

Tags: c++

お世話になります。
Kdenliveというオープンソースの動画編集ツールをGitからダウンロードして、
ソースコードを書き換えてビルドして、UIなどを改造したいのですがビルドに手間取っています。

私がやりたい事は、下記のようなことです。
1）GitからローカルにKdenliveファイルをダウンロード。
2）ローカルにダウンロードしたファイル（ソースコード）を書き換え。
3）書き直したローカルのソースコードをビルドします。
4）新しく構築されたKdenliveを使用します。

【今できている事】
Craftを使用したビルドには成功しました。
※コンパイラーには、MinGWを使いました。
※OSはWindows10です。

【できていない事】
ローカルのKdenliveのソースコードを書き換えてビルドしても何一つ変わりません。
ソースファイルを削除してビルドしても結果は変わりません。
おそらく、ローカルに落としてきたファイルを対象にしていないのではないかと、思います。

Craftというオープンソースのメタビルドシステムおよびパッケージマネージャー必要みたいなのですが、
Craftがローカルにダウンロードしたファイルをビルドすることは可能ですか？

または、Craftの使用に関係なく、ローカルにダウンロードされたKdenliveをビルドする方法がある場合は、教えていただけたら幸いです。
ソースコードの編集はVisualStudio2019を使う予定です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

・kdenliveのGitサイト
https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive

・CraftのGitサイト
https://github.com/KDE/craft

・参考URL
https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_an ... ce/Windows
https://community.kde.org/Kdenlive/Deve ... _using_MXE

Comment: gitとgithubはフランスとフランスパンぐらいの違いがあります。また、質問は入手元に関係がないと思いますのでタグを削除しました。

Answer (score 0):

Craft については回答できませんが、kdenlive のリポジトリにあるマニュアルを見る限り、一般的な手順で通常通りコンパイルもできそうです。
(依存ライブラリの導入やコンパイル環境が整っているのが前提)

[Build and install the projects](https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive/blob/master/dev-docs/build.md#build-and-install-the-projects)

> ```
> INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/.local # or any other choice, the easiest would be to leave it empty ("")
> JOBS=4
>
> # Only if you want to compile MLT manually
> cd mlt
> mkdir build && cd build
> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_PREFIX
> make -j$JOBS
> make install
> # 'sudo make install' if INSTALL_PREFIX is not user-writable
>
> # Kdenlive
> cd ../../kdenlive
> mkdir build && cd build
> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_PREFIX -DKDE_INSTALL_USE_QT_SYS_PATHS=ON -DRELEASE_BUILD=OFF
> ```

> ```
> make -j$JOBS
> make install
> # 'sudo make install' if INSTALL_PREFIX is not user-writable
> ```